# Wordpress Cache issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching

I've got some issues with caching process of my WordPress site: when I add a new product in my site it will be available to buy, but when a customer logs in his account to buy the new product, he's not able to see the new product and needs to use CTRL+F5 to be able to see it.

I used this code to fix the cache issue:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 15 day"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 15 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 15 day"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 15 day"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

By the way I'm using Wordfence plugin in my site. I also used the `islogin()` WordPress function to fix the issue but it's not working...

Is there any solution to fix the problem?

Comment: are you using any plugin to do the cache ??

Comment: Try changing the `text/html` value - see some examples here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html